# Registering Entity in Objectify having issue during test cases

Tags: java, spring, objectify

We have an project developed with Objectify4 and Spring3.1 and deployed and running on GAE and we are using IDE as STS.

When I do project build locally using Maven(cmd `mvn install`) the test cases are failing and throwing the following exception.

From the exception I observe it is failing while injecting `Class1Service` service class in test class `Class1UnitTest` (this is not only in this test class it is giving same exception in every test class wherever we are injecting any service class that extends `AbstractBaseImpl`).

In the exception stacktrace I see it is pointing to line of registering the Entity class(EntityClassA) in  `AbstractBaseImpl`.
In the Entitiy class `EntityClassA` we have used `@Mapify`, if I remove the `@Mapify` annotation in the entity class the test case are running without any bean initialisation issues.
I tried building project from STS and also from command still getting the same issue.

From the functionality point of view the application is working fine if I skip the testcases while building.Can anyone see similar issue with the entity having `@Mapify` defined and getting issue while registering in test case.

Thanks for your time

Here are the details,

**EntityClassA.java**

```
@Entity
public class EntityClassA {

    @Index @Mapify( ChildClassAMapper.class ) 
    private Map<Integer, ChildClassA> intervalToReward = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

    @Embed
    public static class ChildClassA extends ClassA {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 49769454099624971L;
        private int …;
        private long …;


        public ChildClassA(  ) {
            …..
        }
    }

    public static class ChildClassAMapperMapper implements Mapper<Integer, ChildClassA> {

        @Override
        public Integer getKey( ChildClassA value ) {
            return value.getInterval();
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstractBaseImpl.java**

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractBaseImpl implements BaseService {

    static {
Line-12     ObjectifyService.register( EntityClassA.class );
    }
}
```

**ChallengeServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Class1ServiceImpl extends AbstractBaseImpl implements Class1Service {

    // method to store data using objectify..

}
```

**CoreBaseTest.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration( 
    locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/core-applicationContext.xml" } )
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
public abstract class CoreBaseTest {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper( 
        new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy(), 
        new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig(),
        new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig(), 
        new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig() );
}
```

**Class1UnitTest.java**

```
public class Class1UnitTest extends CoreBaseTest {

    @Resource( name = "class1Service" ) 
    private Class1Service class1Service;

    //Testcases…

}
```

**core-applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="class1Service" class="com.suvs.app.core.spring.services.Class1ServiceImpl" />
```

**Exception**

```
TestCrud(test.core.Class1UnitTest')  Time elapsed: 0.163 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test.core.Class1UnitTest': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'class1Service' defined in URL [file:/Users/suvs/core-app/target/classes/META-INF/spring/core-applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'class1Service' defined in URL [file:/Users/suvs/core-app/target/classes/META-INF/spring/core-applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:443)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:417)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.enterCollection(CreateContext.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.(ClassTranslator.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EmbedClassTranslatorFactory.create(EmbedClassTranslatorFactory.java:43)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.MapifyTranslatorFactory.create(MapifyTranslatorFactory.java:62)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.(ClassTranslator.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityClassTranslator.(EntityClassTranslator.java:46)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.(Transmog.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.register(Registrar.java:74)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.register(ObjectifyFactory.java:180)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.register(ObjectifyService.java:62)
    **at com.suvs.app.core.spring.services.AbstractBaseImpl.(AbstractBaseImpl.java:12)**
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 45 more

Comment: This question is missing the most important clue - the stacktrace :)

Comment: Added the stacktrace. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does ChildClassA also contain a collection, thus you are trying to nest two embedded collections? It looks like it from that stacktrace. This is not possible in Objectify4. I highly recommend the upgrade to 5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,we don’t have any collections used in ‘ChildClassA’ and we have field ‘@EmbedMap private Map<String, Integer> helperIdToQty = new HashMap<>();’ in superclass ‘ClassA’ but i tried to remove this field and checked it is still giving same exception.Like i said this happens only when the testcases run while building(mvn install).i surprised the app functionality is not throwing any similar exceptions and the entity read/write operations working as expected.

Comment: Try to boil it down to a minimal test case without any spring stuff. You will probably also get better error messages with Objectify5.